# No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have this database configuration to at my `Startup` class in .NET Core 3.1 Web Api project.

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
        var abcConnString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("abcConnString");
        services.RegisterAbcSqlServer<ABCContext>(abcConnString);

        var xyzConnString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("xyzConnString");
        services.RegisterXyzSqlServer<XYZContext>(xyzConnString);

        // code removed for brevity.
  }
```

and

```
public static class RegisterDbContext
{        
    public static void RegisterAbcSqlServer<T>(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString)
        where T : DbContext, IAbcContext
    {
        var migrationsAssembly = typeof(RegisterDbContext).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;
        services.AddDbContext<T>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, 
            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly))); 
    }

    public static void RegisterXyzSqlServer<T>(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString)
                where T : DbContext, IXyzContext
    {
        var migrationsAssembly = typeof(RegisterDbContext).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;
        services.AddDbContext<T>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)));
    }
}
```

I can build without error. But when I perform EF Core add-migration, it hits error:

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A
> provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring
> method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider.
> If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type
> accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and
> passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

Comment: What does your `DbContext` look like? Do you have a constructor that takes a `DbContextOptions`?

Comment: Oh, one of my context miss out its constructor. Thanks David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this error when there is no way for the DI framework to configure the provider by injecting a `DbContextOptions`. So you just need to add a constructor that will accept one, or add a parameter for a `DbContextOptions` to be passed in. For example:

```
public class XYZContext : DbContext
{
    // Add this constructor
    public XYZContext (DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }  

}
```